# "Error: Provider not set or invalid" When accessing contract methods

Tags: web3js, contract-development, javascript, ethereumjs, address.call

I have write a contract and deployed it through remix-ethereum IDE. That process goes alright. While accessing functions of contract through web3 in javascript I get following error
Error: Provider not set or invalid"

It is noted that in the console the first address comes through following code
console.log(web3.eth.defaultAccount)

Complete Code.

```
let web3 = new Web3(Web3.currentProvider)  
async function contract() {

    accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0] 
    console.log(web3.eth.defaultAccount)
    var toAddress = "0x88c24A263802547F882A7F9cA0Ef58980Fe9f6f2"
    var accountAddress = '0x4a2499F46e00C25d6AFA7CC1cfa47cd69538aE61'
    var abi = [
        {
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "a",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "getValue",
            "outputs": [],
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "showValue",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        }
    ]
    var contractAddress ="0x3A4026a2613bAa8853e6fF29600f57cF5A9f9Ba1";
    var sampleContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)
    console.log(sampleContract.options.address)
    sampleContract.methods.getValue(1).send({
        from: web3.eth.defaultAccount, // default from address
        gasPrice: '20000000000' // default gas price in wei, 20 gwei in this case
    })
    sampleContract.methods.showValue().call(function(error,result) {
        console.log(error)
        console.log(result)
    })
}

contract()
```

[image: Error]

Comment: How are u connecting ur web3 to ur running blockchain ? Can u show the whole code

Comment: Agreed with @MajdTL. If this is all the code, you are missing the part where you specify the provider (as the error explicitely says).

Comment: let web3 = new Web3(Web3.currentProvider) Through this I connect with the metamask. I didnt understand how to specify provider. Kindly explain it.

Comment: You need to connect web3 to a blockchain, remix run a small blockchain in memory for you. But when u leave remix u need to provide your own blockchain. U can use for testen something called Ganache which provide a simple simulated blockchain for u and then you can connect it with your web3

Comment: it will look something like this -> Const web3 = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(„http://127.0.0.1:<ganache-port>“);

Comment: U can similarly connect to some test net using Infura , but then u need test ether

Comment: To connect to metamask there is many tutorials and u script should run in browser

Answer (score 1):

With the latest changes use `window.ethereum` as provider after the user has granted permission

```
async function contract() {
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
```